# Are the google custom searches getting blocked now?

Tags: support, search-engine

I created a [custom google search](http://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=004055899985439311584:twnxsyrgj4a) a little while back that searched the "family" of sites.

I went to do a search and got this error:

> Forbidden
>
> Your client does not have permission
>   to get URL
>   /custom?cx=[LOTS OF GIBBERISH]
>   from this server. (Client IP address: 63.230.246.50)
>
> We apologize for your inconvenience,
>   but this request could not be
>   processed. Please click here to
>   continue your search on Google.

I've tried a few times over the course of an hour and I get the same message. Are other folks running into this issue (I think there are a few of these custom searches out there) or is it just me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmm, that's a little creepy (especially with the IP address there).

I tried making a custom standard search myself for the trilogy sites, checked the "I accept the terms" checkbox, and clicked the Next button, and got "Bad Request" several times before it finally accepted it.  Is buggy, no?

Here is the new search:

http://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=014887575466180363695:g0ck1r1qso4

If it doesn't work for you, that probably means that it only works for me (muahaha!).  If it does work, that may mean there is a bandwidth limit that was exceeded on yours, or that a time limit was exceeded.  Is your Google account current?

There was a mention somewhere on the internets about an IFrame problem, but I don't see how that could apply here.  Are you running it inside an IFrame?

Comment: Nope, no iFrame issue, just a direct link via Chrome. I had a subdomain address originally setup to forward there, but I kept testing by going to the direct link. I did post the link earlier in MSO, but I didn't think it was gaining THAT much traffic. 8^D

Comment: It's hard to believe that Google would want to throttle the traffic anyway; it says in their TOS that they display ads on your custom search page, so it's just another money-making avenue for them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But there might be a courtesy limit like on Google APIs for custom searching...