# Fast way to search stackoverflow.com using google

Tags: discussion, google-chrome, addon

Everytime I have to search something on stackoverflow.com using Google I have to type the rather long

```
<search term> site:stackoverflow.com
```

Is there some way to speedup the process, so that I need not type the whole 23 characters of `site:stackoverflow.com` each and every time?

I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: website questions are offtopic on Super User.  questions about the Stack Overflow trilogy should be asked on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).  this will be migrated there shortly.

Comment: @quack: this belonged on super user. He asked about stackoverflow.com, but he could have asked the same question about microsoft.com or any other website. Just because the example mentions stack overflow it doesn't mean it belongs on meta. PS: also this isn't a "website question", it's a question about google chrome =o

Comment: @kop: there are several threads here on Meta about using Greasemonkey or other addons.  you're right that this question is about using Google Chrome, but it's also Stack-Overflow-specific.  i think it's better here on Meta than on Super User.

Comment: Err, make a form that does it for you?

Comment: @Tim Post: what *form*?

Comment: Related: [How does Chrome know how to search Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55646/how-does-chrome-know-how-to-search-meta)

Comment: http://sitecomber.com/cu/StackOverflowq9zcom

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Right click on the url bar. Set up search providers. Add a new one.
Name: `Superuser`
Keyword: `su`
url: `http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%s site:superuser.com` 
Hope this is what you meant.

Comment: To use the search above, type `su` into the omnibar (URL bar) and hit the `TAB` key.  After that just type your query and hit `ENTER`.

Comment: @Fujishiro: thanks! exactly what I wanted!

Comment: +1 for the "Edit Search Engines..." shortcut menu in the URL bar's context menu.

Comment: If you're pretty sure you'll want the first result from Google's search, add `&btnI` to the end of the URL, which will flip on the "I Feel Lucky" behavior to take you straight to the first result.

Comment: They should call that "russian roulette". One year ago there were still poisoned searches out there. (Like searching for a safe term and clicking on an image got you to some weird site.)

Comment: How to add search provider? I can't see this option

Answer (score 5):

Why would you do that? Stackoverflow.com has its own search and search plugin. I'm using Chrome, too, which picks up search plugins when it finds them. So, if you visit stackoverflow.com relatively often, you can start typing it (for me it's enough to type "sta") in the address bar and you'll see at the right of it "Press `<Tab>` to search Stack Overflow". Press tab, enter your query and press enter.

Comment: That is amazing, you have made my day.

Comment: Because google search is **a lot** better than SE search...

Comment: Custom shortcuts for a few common searches can speed up your navigaton a lot. Wikipedia/image/map search and translate are the ones I use daily; documentation sites can be nice too.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DuckDuckGo](http://duckduckgo.com). Syntax:

```
!so %s => http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%s
!su %s => http://superuser.com/search?q=%s
!sf %s => http://serverfault.com/search?q=%s
```

**Coming soon** I've [suggested](http://duckduckgo.com/newbang.html) a [bang](http://duckduckgo.com/bang.html) on these.

```
!mso %s => http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%s
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `as_sitesearch` URL argument.  For example:

```
http://www.google.com/search?as_q=YOURQUERY&as_sitesearch=stackoverflow.com
```

This form should work as well:

```
<form method="GET" action="http://www.google.com/search">
<input type="hidden" name="as_sitesearch" value="stackoverflow.com">
<input name="as_q">
<input type="submit" value="Search StackOverrflow">
</form>
```

If you simply want to add a search engine to Google Chrome, Fujishiro's answer is what you are looking for.  You can replace `YOURQUERY` in the URL above with `%s` when editing your Google Chrome search engines.

Comment: I didn't get how the form worked. I though Google had a framework of their own and didn't use PHP. How does `GET` work then? How does the form return results?

Comment: @YatharthROCK The HTML snippet I listed is not related to PHP.  A form in HTML is a tool for performing an HTTP GET or POST request with GET parameters or form-encoded POST data.  You should look up **HTML forms and HTTP methods**.  Here's one link that may shed some light on the issue for you: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html

Comment: I will, thanks for clearing that up. BTW, can you tell me what's the difference between `http://www.google.com` and `http://google.com`? From what I know, the 'things' before the domain tell the name of the dedicated server (like `plus.google.com` has a dedicated server just for that). `plus.google.com` would also be the same as `google.com/plus`. The `www.` is just some placeholder that tells the browser explicitly to go to the 'main' server.

Comment: Do correct me where-ever I'm wrong (probably everywhere)

Comment: Those "things" are part of the domain (a subdomain within it) which is a hierarchical structure.  Domains are linked to IP addresses via domain name system (DNS).  Multiple domains can point to the same IP and web servers located behind that IP can route traffic accordingly based on the domain given.  I would look up how domain name servers work.  Unfortunately I don't have a great suggestion for a single resource that might teach all of this information.  I hope you can find one that works for you.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firefox, this will be helpful:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/google-stackoverflow/

Answer (score 0):

Some have created a custom Google search for that:

- See [search stackoverflow (and serverfault) from firefox search box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27809/search-stackoverflow-and-serverfault-from-firefox-search-box) (and a reference to the internal non-Google search [is built-in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27809/search-stackoverflow-and-serverfault-from-firefox-search-box/28056#28056))
- See the link at [Are the google custom searches getting blocked now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23231/are-the-google-custom-searches-getting-blocked-now)

Answer (score 0):

I find adding the keyword 'stackoverflow' to my google search works almost as well as restricting the results to the site and saves me a good 9 characters of typing.

```
<search term> stackoverflow
```

is usually as good as

```
<search term> site:stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: When searching for duplicates I don't want anyone referring to SOFU to clutter my search results. Using site: excludes all irrelevant sites

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you an extension [SO Search Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dkacnjhkeinnidojdabjgcipkgmigmof)

You just type in the address bar "so your_search_term" and here you are :)

Comment: No need to "bloat" your chrome with more extensions... You can [manually setup custom search engines](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95653) in chrome...

Comment: @Lix, cool. I didn't know about this feature. I assume it didn't exist when that extension was written. And more than that - adding an extension is a bit easier than creating own search query in the browser settings.

Comment: Easier - yes, but each extension that you add to chrome makes it eat more and more resources... If there is an alternative method such as a userscript, it is preferred over an extension...