# What happened to "tab to search" on Stack Overflow on Chrome?

Tags: discussion, google-chrome

I used to be able to start typing in `stackoverflow.com` in Chrome and then tab to search within stackoverflow.com. But it doesn't work any more. What happened?

Comment: Found the solution. http://duklee.net/post/23559833709/how-to-make-tab-to-search-on-stackoverflow-com-work

Comment: Sorta related: [How does Chrome know how to search Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55646/how-does-chrome-know-how-to-search-meta)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you [linked](http://duklee.net/post/23559833709/how-to-make-tab-to-search-on-stackoverflow-com-work) in the comments:

> At some point of updating chrome, this neat feature stopped working.
>   And I dug around “settings” and figured out how fix this issue. Hope
>   this helps.
>
> 1. Go to “Settings”
> 2. Click on “Manage Search Engines”
> 3. If you ever used Stackoverflow.com. It should be in “Other search engines” section.
> 4. Move your mouse over and click on blue “Make Default” button. That will move it over to  ”default search settings” section.
> 5. If you want Google to be your default search engine, move your mouse over it and click on blue “Make Default” button again.
>
> That’s it. As long as websites are in “default search settings”
>   section, “Press tab to search” works.